# Send Email via MailEnvelope

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a specific range into mail (with images).

```
Sub Send_Range_Or_Whole_Worksheet_with_MailEnvelope()
'Working in Excel 2002-2016
Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim rng As Range

On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
Set Sendrng = Worksheets("EMAIL").Range("B2:W41")

'Remember the activesheet
Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

With Sendrng

    ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
    .Parent.Select

    'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
    Set rng = ActiveCell

    'Select the range you want to mail
    .Select

    ' Create the mail and send it
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
        ' some header text to the email body.
        .Introduction = "This is test mail 2."

        With .Item
            .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EMAIL").Range("Z1").Value
            .CC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EMAIL").Range("Z1").Value
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EMAIL").Range("D1").Value
            .Display
        End With

    End With

    'select the original ActiveCell
    rng.Select
End With

'Activate the sheet that was active before you run the macro
AWorksheet.Select

StopMacro:
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Why does MailEnvelope show for one second and nothing happen afterwards?

I replaced `.Send` with `.Display` but nothing changed. Alternatively I tried to use the RNGtoHTML code but this code does not copy images (I have dynamic linked picture in the sheet "EMAIL").

Answer (score 1):

Trying stepping through it.

When you run the script, it will display when you get to this line of code,

```
.display
```

but then the code below is ran and which will cause it to stop displaying.

```
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
```

If you step through the code, you should be able to see your content until you get to the line of code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you use

.Display

but you don't wait for send and then close the Envelope without sending:
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

- just comment it and the dialog will stay there for you to send it.

If you need to use .Send, or .Display doesn't work at all:

- running outlook in admin mode solves it
- changing MS Outlook setting for Programatic access* to "warn me if.." solved it kind of for me (displaying the annoying dialog when using .Send)
- put MsgBox Err.description at the end to debug your error

  MsgBox Err.description
  End Sub
- **still trying to figure out the actual solution**.

The mail send macro worked for me but stopped after while. Not really sure why. I even tried to add some registry keys (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e2c89fec-beb3-4224-a6cb-112704406907/cannot-change-programmatic-access-security?forum=outlook). But that didn't work.

*What is most funny is that if you disable MS outlook warning for programatic access (https://www.slipstick.com/developer/change-programmatic-access-options/)
- start MS O in admin and go to that setting - it stops displaying the warnig but also stops the request and the functionality. The usual microsoft behaviour these days....