# Runtime Error while using the Excel Sheet's MailEnvelope object

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to open an Excel file, selecting a range which I need to send as **email body**. I am doing this using the MailEnvelope object of Excel Sheet.

I get an error while running the following vbscript code snippet. This code, at times, throws the error "Unknown Runtime Error" at line mentioned in the comments. Due to inconsistent nature of the error, I am just confused.

When I run the code, I observe that the mail envelope is not getting visible even though I have `objBook.EnvelopeVisible = True`.

**Code:**

```
set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.visible = true
objexcel.DisplayAlerts = false
set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(strOutputFilePath)
set objSheet = objBook.Sheets("TestResults")
objSheet.Range("A1:T60").Select
objBook.EnvelopeVisible = True         '<-------- Getting the error here
With objSheet.MailEnvelope.Item        '<-------- If I comment the line above, I get the same error on this line
        .To = strToList
        .cc = strCCList
        .subject = "Investment Platform - Test Execution Summary - "&strExecEnv&" - " & date
        .attachments.add strOutputFilePath
        .send
End With
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

[image]

---

## Solved

I realized the Excel workbook I was trying to open was in the System Drive(C: Drive) on which I do not have enough privileges. I moved the file to another local drive on which I have full access and the code ran. The answers mentioned by others are also working.

Comment: set a stop point here: objSheet.Range("A1:T60").Select and look if objBook and objSheet are nothing, plz

Comment: @Denyo The code does select the Range `A1:T60` which means that the reference to the Sheet is just fine in the line `objSheet.Range("A1:T60").Select`. The selection is not visible in the screenshot because the focus is on the Error message. I tried to capture it in screenshot but could not do it. In short, `objSheet` is not `nothing`

Comment: Ok, objSheet is set. Have you checked objBook also? btw, which excel version do you have in use?

Comment: @Denyo Yes the variable `objBook` has also not lost the reference to the desired workbook. I wrote the line `msgbox objBook.path` just before selecting the Range and it displayed the correct path of the workbook. So, the references are just fine.

Comment: After the select line, you may need a `with selection` line and an `end with` at the end

Comment: @Davesexcel I am not sure If I got that correctly. Even If I use `With Selection...End With`, what methods and properties of the `selection` object can I use to send the selected range in the email's body. I don't think I can use the MailEnvelope object in that case.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error, your code seem to be working with me (office 32 bits 2016) I think you may have to add `DoEvents` after the selection and after the `objBook.EnvelopeVisible = True`. Let me know if that works

Comment: @Sgdva Thanks for mentioning the `doevents` here. I will do some research on that now. Also, As I said, this code was working fine this morning but I have suddenly started getting this issue. A few days back also, I had gotten the same issue but it got resolved somehow. It is quite weird behavior.

Comment: If `Doevents` doesn't catch it, you may try to use `Application.Wait` . It sounds like a processor time related bug to me

Comment: I attempting some research and found a link where the author doesn't think it works if the outlook is a newer version than the Excel. Is it possible that's the issue? https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail3.htm

Comment: @Mistella I have checked that both the outlook and the excel are of exact same version.

Comment: Someone else had issues with the MailEnvelope a while back. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43616904/9259306) has some suggestions to try.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excel code example of using Envelope.

```
Sub EmAiLtoDave()
'Working in Excel 2002-2013
    Dim Sendrng As Range, s As String, msg As String

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    Set Sendrng = Range("A3:O23")
    Sendrng.Select
    With Sendrng

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            '.Introduction = msg

            With .Item
                .To = "david.morrison@somewhere.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Hi"
                .Send
            End With

        End With
    End With

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

as Davesexcel mentioned, following could help you:

```
objSheet.Range("A1:T60").Select
With Selection
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
End With
```

i created this test and here it does work (Excel 2010):

```
    Sub test()


    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objBook As Object
    Dim objSheet As Object

    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set objBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("pathtotestfile")
    Set objSheet = objBook.Sheets("testtable")
    With Selection
        objBook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

can you test this plz with a new testfile?

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Denyo. But this code did not work. In Excel Macro too, I wrote this code and it did not make the envelope visible on screen and threw the error `Run Time Error '1004' Application defined or Object-defined error` :(

Comment: im sorry, i have to apologize...it does not work properly. im trying to fix.